# how to write a periodically repeating function for telegrams bot deployed on Heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, scheduled-tasks, telegram-bot

I wrote a function that should send a message to users at a certain time:

```
def send_wishes_loop():
    connection = psycopg2.connect(...)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour  

    cursor.execute("""SELECT userid FROM usersdata WHERE morning_time={}""".format(hour))
    for userid in cursor:
        if userid:
            bot.send_message(userid[0] , random.choices(wishes_list.good_morning_wishes))
    ....

    cursor.close() 
    connection.commit() 
time.sleep((61-datetime.datetime.now().minute)*60))
```

and put it in a separate thread

```
t1 = Thread(target=bot.polling())
t2 = Thread(send_wishes_loop())
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

but it does not work. 
How can I implement this function, fix it? 
In the heroku documentation I read about Heroku Scheduler, 
but did not understand how to use it. Please, help me...

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use Heroku Scheduler.

I suggest you define a script (with `if __name__ == '__main__':`) that calls your function `send_wishes_loop()` (without the last line that contains `sleep`).

The you add the script to [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) as a new job.
As you can see in the docs, there is a nice web interface where you just need to add the invocation of your script (probably something like `python your_script.py`) and set the interval.

Comment: Feel free to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped you